# How do I highlight the entire quote with both quotes given that a keyword is found using RegEx?

Tags: regex

Forgive me, just got started with regex today. What I've come up with so far to my understanding is `\".*\bkeyword\b.*\"`. I'm not too sure how to handle special characters such as / or ; . So some help please?

What I need to detect is goes something like this.

```
"Mozilla/5.0   (X11;   Ubuntu;   Linux   x86_64;   rv:31.0) 
 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

If I type the word Mozilla, the quotes and text in between will be highlighted. And look sorta like this.
[image]

Comment: That depends on where you use the regex, but in most cases, `"[^"]*\bkeyword\b[^"]*"` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
"[^"]*\bMozilla\b[^"]*"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5dpHFO/1)

**Details**

- `"` - a double quote
- `[^"]*` - a negated character class that matches any char other than `"` zero or more times (due to the `*` quantifier)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Mozilla` - any keyword consisting of word chars (letters, digits or/and `_`)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[^"]*` - a negated character class that matches any char other than `"` zero or more times.

When declaring the regex inside double quoted string literals, you may have to escape `"` (=> `"\""`) and `\b` (=> `\\b`) once. There are ways to avoid using (too many) backslashes, but that depends on what language and notation you are using.